# which sql join query should i use?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm a noob in using complex query.. so i'm a little bit confused around here..

here are the problem :

i had 2 table, the first one is

employee :

```
empID name  branchID   etc
 1    ab      1        ...
 2    abc     4        ...
 3    ad      4        ...
```

and the second table was

employeeAttendance :

```
empID   attDate     hourIn  hourOut  etc
  1    05-06-2013    12.00   14.00   ...
  1    05-07-2013    10.00   14.00   ...
  1    05-10-2013    09.00   12.00   ...
  2    05-06-2013    08.00   14.00   ...
  2    05-10-2013    08.00   10.00   ...
  3    05-09-2013    11.00   15.00   ...
```

and what i'm trying to accomplish is this view :

```
empID name   attDate     hourIn  hourOut  etc
  1    ab  05-06-2013    12.00   14.00   ...
  2    abc 05-06-2013    08.00   14.00   ...
  3    ad  05-06-2013    null    null    ...
  1    ab  05-07-2013    10.00   14.00   ...
  2    abc 05-07-2013    null    null    ...
  3    ad  05-07-2013    null    null    ...
  1    ab  05-09-2013    null    null    ...
  2    abc 05-09-2013    null    null    ...
  3    ad  05-09-2013    11.00   15.00   ...
  1    ab  05-10-2013    09.00   12.00   ...
  2    abc 05-10-2013    08.00   10.00   ...
  3    ad  05-10-2013    null    null    ...
```

i'm using sql server management studio 2008, it's funny, i felt this is so easy but i couldn't make it afterall, i have tried to use LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN, and even CROSS JOIN, but none of them give me the result i want..

the one that nearly give me the answer was CROSS JOIN but the ID didn't match because CROSS JOIN didn't use ON clause.. and when i add WHERE, it automatically became INNER JOIN..

so did i miss something in here?
sorry if this question is silly, and sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: You have to use both `CROSS JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` to achieve this result set. Working demo in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16536344/309086).

Comment: yea, i have try it and it's work.. thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 WITH DateList AS(
 SELECT DISTINCT E.EmpiD,E.Name,EA.AttDate FROM EmployeeAttendance EA
 CROSS JOIN Employee E )

 SELECT
    DL.empID,
    DL.name,
    DL.attDate,
    EA.hourIn,
    EA.hourOut,
    EA.etc
FROM DateList DL
LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeAttendance EA
ON DL.EmpID = EA.EmpID AND 
DL.AttDate = EA.AttDate
ORDER BY DL.AttDate,DL.EmpId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d64c9/9)

Raj

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT e.empID, name, attDay, hourIn, hourOut
FROM employee e
CROSS JOIN (SELECT distinct attDate AS attDay FROM employeeAttendance) AS allDates
LEFT OUTER JOIN employeeAttendance att
ON e.empID = att.empID and attDay = attDate
```

Demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53f66/5).

Answer (score 0):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT employee.empID, employee.name,   employeeAttendance.attDate,employeeAttendance.hourIn,  employeeAttendance.hourOut,  employeeAttendance.etc 
FROM employee  
FULL OUTER JOIN employeeAttendance on employee.empID= employeeAttendance.empID
```

Comment: ok, i want the result to display all of the employee members, in every date in employeeAttendance.attDate. whether they had row in employeeAttendance or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15557)

**Query**:

```
select a.empID, a.name,   employeeAttendance.attDate,employeeAttendance.hourIn,
employeeAttendance.hourOut
from employeeAttendance full join 

(select empID, name,  branchID,attDate from emp
, (select distinct attDate from employeeAttendance)b)a 

on employeeAttendance.empID = a.empID  and employeeAttendance.attDate=a.attDate
order by empid,attDate desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15557/2)**:

```
| EMPID | NAME |    ATTDATE | HOURIN | HOUROUT |
------------------------------------------------
|     1 |   ab | 05-10-2013 |  09.00 |   12.00 |
|     1 |   ab | 05-06-2013 |  12.00 |   14.00 |
|     1 |   ab |     (null) | (null) |  (null) |
|     2 |  abc | 05-10-2013 |  08.00 |   10.00 |
|     2 |  abc | 05-06-2013 |  08.00 |   14.00 |
|     2 |  abc |     (null) | (null) |  (null) |
|     3 |   ad | 05-09-2013 |  11.00 |   15.00 |
|     3 |   ad |     (null) | (null) |  (null) |
|     3 |   ad |     (null) | (null) |  (null) |
```